# Executive Hive query in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, hive

I have no errors while executing below query in hive (beeline). But the same query fails with below error message when executed from Python using pyspark. How can I tune python code to use native hive engine instead of pyspark to execute below query please ?

```
select count(com_dq), col1 from ( select col1, case when col2 not in (select distinct col3 from hive_Schema_name_1.table_name_1 where col4=1 AND col5='ABC' ) then 1 else 0 end as com_dq from hive_Schema_name_2.table_name_2 ) as data group by col1;
```

Below error when above query executed using Pyspark from Python: AnalysisException: IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in Filter/Join and a few commands:

I have also tried using hivecontext sql, but getting the same above error.

Comment: `spark.sql()` has some limitations -- your example being one.

Answer (score 0):

hive sometime doesnt support sub queries in SELECT clause. You need to rewrite the SQL using left join with where clause. You can use below SQL which uses left join to mimic not in clause.

```
SELECT Count(com_dq),
       col1
FROM  (SELECT col1,
              CASE
                WHEN rs.col3 IS NULL THEN 1
                ELSE 0
              END AS com_dq
       FROM   hive_schema_name_2.table_name_2
              LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col3
                         FROM   hive_schema_name_1.table_name_1
                         WHERE  col4 = 1
                                AND col5 = 'ABC') rs
                     ON rs.col3 = col2
       WHERE  rs.col3 IS NULL) rs2
GROUP  BY 2
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, the query I shared in my question works perfectly when executed in beeline in Hive, but not through pyspark ? and how to pass instructions to pyspark to execute query in a format hive understands and not pyspark ?

Comment: i think @samkart gave you explanation.

Comment: limitations are in this link https://dwgeek.com/apache-spark-sql-supported-subqueries-and-examples.html/

Comment: Got one more Q reg Pyspark & Pandas
What is the most efficient method to calculate the size of Pyspark & Pandas DF in MB/GB ?

Comment: i think you can create one more question and close this one by accepting the answer...

Comment: yeah ..did it here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74289991/pyspark-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Did this answers your question?