# Size of PySpark & Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

What is the most efficient method to calculate the size of Pyspark & Pandas DF in MB/GB ?

I searched on this website, but couldn't get correct answer.

Comment: i know in pandas you can do `pandas_df.info()`

Comment: Thanks, that gives me the size of DF with other details...any method to get the size of df instead of whole info ?